# How to Forbid the usage of a PreRelease version of a nuget package in Release Pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to "fail" the release if there are nugget packages in pre-release versions?

Maybe there is a task already for this in Azure DevOps, or maybe there's a way to do it with Powershell?

Comment: Do you mean - if in the `packags.config` there is a nuget package with pre-relesae version?

Comment: Note: if you're building a *package*, NU5104 does this for you already; I assume that this is a top-level deployable "thing" then?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I don't have a package.config file. It's a .Net Core Solution, and the nuggets are referenced. As I understand the .csproj's files are keeping the references for nuget packages. I just want to be aware if between all nugets, there is at least one in pre-release. If there is one, then I want to fail the Release.

Comment: @MarcGravell No, I'm not building a nuget. I just want to be aware, if the solution that I'm deploying, has some packages with pre-release versions. When that's the case, I would like to 'fail' the release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the `.csproj` file with PowerShell and check if pre-release exist, if yes make an error:

```
[xml]$csproj = Get-Content path/to/csproj/file # e.g. $(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)/myproject/myproject.csproj
$versions = $csproj.Projects.ItemGroup.PackageReference.Version
$versions.ForEach({

   # Pre-releases are with '-' symbol, e.g. 1.0.0-beta
   if($_ -match "(?<number>\d-)")
   {
       Write-Error "Pre-release exist: $_"
   }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution (if you want to take packets from SLN file) for this can be the following:

```
Get-Content .\SolutionName.sln |
where { $_ -match "Project.+, ""(.+)""," } |
foreach { $matches[1] } |
% { Get-Content $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
Find "<PackageReference Include" } |
Sort-Object -Unique |
% { if($_ -match "-test") { Write-Host "You're using a PreRelease Version for the following Package $($_)"} }
```

Change **SolutionName** with the name of your solution. 
Change **-test** with the suffix of your prerelease package(in my case it was Version="4.1.2-test").

Or if you want to take nugets from **csproj** files recursively

```
get-childitem "$(get-location)" -recurse |
where {$_.extension -eq ".csproj"}|
% { Get-Content $_.FullName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
Find "<PackageReference Include" } |
Sort-Object -Unique |
% { if($_ -match "-test") { Write-Error "You're using a PreRelease Version for the following Package $($_)"} }
```

Again, change the **-test** with what you need.